# Deadlock in nested loop MPI (Python mpi4py)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

I can't figure out why this nested loop MPI won't stop (i.e. deadlock). I know that most MPI users are based on C++ / C / Fortran, and I'm using Python's `mpi4py` package here, but I suspect that it's not an issue of the programming language but my misunderstanding of MPI itself.

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# simple_mpi_run.py

from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np 

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
rank = comm.Get_rank() 
size = comm.Get_size() 
root_ = 0 

# Define some tags for MPI  
TAG_BLOCK_IDX = 1

num_big_blocks = 5

for big_block_idx in np.arange(num_big_blocks): 

    for worker_idx in (1+np.arange(size-1)): 
        if rank==root_: 
            # send to workers 
            comm.send(big_block_idx,
                    dest = worker_idx, 
                    tag = TAG_BLOCK_IDX) 
            print("This is big block", big_block_idx, 
                    "and sending to worker rank", worker_idx) 

        else:
            # receive from root_ 
            local_block_idx = comm.recv(source=root_, tag=TAG_BLOCK_IDX) 
            print("This is rank", rank, "on big block", local_block_idx)
```

**Batch job script**

The SGE batch job script that runs the above. For illustration purposes, I use `-np 3` to allocate only three processes to the `mpirun`. In the actual application, I'll use far more than just three.

```
#!/bin/bash

# batch_job.sh

#$ -S /bin/bash 
#$ -pe mpi 3
#$ -cwd
#$ -e error.log
#$ -o stdout.log
#$ -R y

MPIPATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/

PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/:/usr/bin/
export PYTHONPATH

PATH=$PATH:$MPIPATH
export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/ 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

mpirun -v -np 3 python3 simple_mpi_run.py
```

**Output**

From `stdout.log`, I see the following output after running `qsub batch_job.sh`:

```
This is big block 0 and sending to worker rank 1
This is rank 1 on big block 0
This is big block 0 and sending to worker rank 2
This is big block 1 and sending to worker rank 1
This is rank 1 on big block 1
This is big block 1 and sending to worker rank 2
This is big block 2 and sending to worker rank 1
This is rank 1 on big block 2
This is big block 2 and sending to worker rank 2
This is big block 3 and sending to worker rank 1
This is rank 1 on big block 3
This is big block 3 and sending to worker rank 2
This is big block 4 and sending to worker rank 1
This is rank 1 on big block 4
This is big block 4 and sending to worker rank 2
This is rank 2 on big block 0
This is rank 2 on big block 1
This is rank 2 on big block 2
This is rank 2 on big block 3
This is rank 2 on big block 4
```

**Problem**

As far as I can tell, this is the *correct* output that I anticipate. However, when I run `qstat`, I can see that the job state is held at `r`, indicating that the job is not complete, even though I have my desired output. I thus suspect that this is an MPI deadlock issue, but despite hours of tinkering here and there, I still can't see the deadlock issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**Edit**

Removed some comment blocks in the code that are irrelevant to the deadlock problem at hand.

Comment: `# In actual code, each worker_idx 
            # does something here and each worker_idx
            # only works on a partition of ` <-- this cannot be that block is code is executed only by the master process

Comment: What am saying is 'each worker' cannot do anything in that block

Comment: The comment blocks cannot be disregarded since you haven't posted sufficient code

Comment: @e4c5 I've edited the blocks to remove all of those comment blocks. If I run them as is with SGE, I get the displayed output, but the entire job does not stop (i.e. always hang in the `r` state in `qstat`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the hang is you swapped the second `for` loop and the `if` clause : non root rank should receive only once from master.

That being said, you'd rather use the MPI collective `MPI_Bcast()` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Here is a rewritten version of your program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# simple_mpi_run.py

from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np 

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
rank = comm.Get_rank() 
size = comm.Get_size() 
root_ = 0 

# Define some tags for MPI  
TAG_BLOCK_IDX = 1

num_big_blocks = 5

for big_block_idx in np.arange(num_big_blocks): 

    if rank==root_: 
        for worker_idx in (1+np.arange(size-1)): 
            # send to workers 
            comm.send(big_block_idx,
                    dest = worker_idx, 
                    tag = TAG_BLOCK_IDX) 
            print("This is big block", big_block_idx, 
                    "and sending to worker rank", worker_idx) 

    else:
        # receive from root_ 
        local_block_idx = comm.recv(source=root_, tag=TAG_BLOCK_IDX) 
        print("This is rank", rank, "on big block", local_block_idx)
```

and here is a more MPI'ish version that uses `MPI_Bcast()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# simple_mpi_run.py

from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np 

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
rank = comm.Get_rank() 
root_ = 0 

num_big_blocks = 5

for big_block_idx in np.arange(num_big_blocks): 

    local_block_idx = comm.bcast(big_block_idx, root=root_)

    if rank==root_: 
            print("This is big block", big_block_idx, 
                    "and broadcasting to all worker ranks")
    else:
        print("This is rank", rank, "on big block", local_block_idx)
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for pointing out that "non root rank should receive only once from master." I'm aware of `bcast` in MPI but for assorted reasons, in my actual work it's easier to deal with point-to-point communication. Nonetheless, much appreciated for the `bcast` version of my question!